# What to stub, in order to test an ActiveRecord validates_uniqueness_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, unit-testing, activerecord

I have a simplified model:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :primary_domain, uniqueness: true
end
```

And I have a test in minitest-spec:

```
describe "primary_domain" do
  it "must be unique" do
    Site.create(primary_domain: "example.com")
    s = Site.new(primary_domain: "example.com")
    s.wont_be valid?
    s.errors.messages.keys.must_include :primary_domain
  end
end
```

But this requires a few roundtrips to the database, which I find to break the concept of a Unit-test. Is there something I can stub to exclude the entire database-layer?

E.g. When using mocha:

```
describe "primary_domain" do
  it "must be unique" do
    Site.stubs(:find_by).with(primary_domain: "example.com").returns([Site.new])
    s = Site.new(primary_domain: "example.com")
    s.wont_be valid?
    s.errors.messages.keys.must_include :primary_domain
  end
end
```

Apparently the uniqueness validator does not use the find_by, but probably some other check. Is there a better candidate to stub out here to achieve the same?

Comment: Might consider using shoulda-matchers. https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#validate_uniqueness_of

Comment: I have Shoulda-matchers, but that does not change the fact that it wants to operate on a "persisted" version. I left the shoulda-syntax out, for clarity.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I suppose you'd have to dig into the rails source to see what to stub.  That sounds dirtier than simply hitting the database though.